# How to deploy wso2 esb version 4.7.0 on apache tomcat 7.0.37?

Tags: tomcat, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to deploy wso2 esb version 4.7.0 on apache tomcat 7.0.37. I have used the following listed articles to do this, But didn't succeeded. All articles are about older versions. Is there any other option to do this.Please help.....

- [Deploy wso2 esb in apache tomcat](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/deploy-wso2-esb-apache-tomcat)
- [How to deploy wso2 esb 3x on apache](http://charithaka.blogspot.in/2010/08/how-to-deploy-wso2-esb-3x-on-apache.html)

Comment: Any particular reasons for this requirement? Please note that ESB now uses high performance transports for proxies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WSO2 Products are no longer recommended to run in other containers such as Tomcat. That's why you can see articles only for older versions. I'm afraid, there is no other option for this.